# Haskell: How is Num held?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

In the following example:

```
> let sum::Num a=> a->a->a; sum a b = a +b
> let partialSum = sum 1
> partialSum 2.0
3.0
```

In step `let partialSum = sum 1` it would appear that a is interpreted as Integer but I suppose Haskell delays this until it can figure out the type (and consequently which typeclass instance to use) until the whole expression is built.
We can interpret this because the ultimate result is Fractional (3.0)

But at this point `let partialSum = sum 1` GHCI has to hold `1`  in memory, I was wondering what does it hold it as?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But at this point `let partialSum = sum 1` GHCi has to hold 1 in memory

Sure, but remember that Haskell number literals are overloaded. In this case, `1` gets stored as `fromInteger (1 :: Integer) :: Num a => a`. `partialSum` holds onto this until it knows what `a` should be. GHCi holds onto only `1` the `Integer`.

Comment: I was wondering if fromIntegral is the only way and only hence only Integer can be used in the above manner. So for example this does not work:``` let f = 1::Float
let d = 2::Double let sum Num::a=> a->a->a; sum a b = a+b let partialSum = sum f partialSum d``` leads to error

Comment: @Ngm You can naturally ensure the literal be of a certain type by adding a type annotation, although unless you force it to WNHF, you have no guarantees an actual literal of that type will be stored at that point. Also worth noting that unboxed literals like `1#` and `1.0#` exist (they map more closely onto value types from other languages, but are used less frequently by Haskell beginners).

Answer (score 7):

The answer can be broken down in two components:

- Typeclass constraints get elaborated as records and they're automatically passed around whenever needed.
- A numeric literal `n` is translated to [`fromInteger n`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromInteger)

So

```
sum :: Num a => a -> a -> a
sum a b = a + b
```

would become:

```
sum' :: RecordNum a -> a -> a -> a
sum' dict a b = (plus dict) a b
```

where

```
data RecordNum a = RecordNum
    { plus :: a -> a -> a
    ; mult :: a -> a -> a
    (...)
    ; fromInteger :: Integer -> a
    }
```

and then

```
partialSum :: Num a => a -> a
partialSum = sum 1
```

becomes

```
partialSum' :: RecordNum a -> a -> a
partialSum' dict = sum' dict (fromInteger dict 1)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be an *integer* literal is translated to `fromInteger n`? `partialSum = sum 2.5` would be interpreted slightly differently.